# add a key value with Symbols chars in Csharp

Tags: c#, powershell, registry

I tried to add this line to a key in registry

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -noexit -file "%1"
```

as you see the value that i want to add contains """" and % and - 
So how can i do it please
i know with Registry.SetValue as here

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command", "Default", @""C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -noexit -file "%1"");
```

[image: Photo the error messages here]
[image: and here also]

but errors popup every time i putted @ at the beginning
but didnt work also 
this key will allow me if i edited it to run powershell script by double click on it
any ideas ?..thx

Comment: Please edit the post and show the code used for insertion.

Comment: Please edit the post and show the error messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put another `"` to escape each `"`

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command", "Default", @"""C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe""-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -noexit -file ""%1""");
```

Comment: The screenshot shows that this is not just an escape issue. The string literal token `@` is missing too.

Comment: thanks alot guys 
yes worked by Furkan Kambay answer

Comment: @vonPryz If you look at the code snippet, you can see that he used string literal, but the `"`s were missing:
`Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command", "Default", @""C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -windowstyle hidden -noexit -file "%1"");`

So it's not my fault that there's two different version of the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting shows the issue. The third parameter is

```
""C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell...
```

Thus, the compiler sees an empty string `""` and unexpected `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell...`

As resolution, use string literal properly

```
@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell...
```